# Top bar Home icon redirects me to http site

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, top-bar, ssl, homepage

The main site link to home in the top bar is still set to `http://stackoverflow.com`, even though I manually load the https version.

Are also affected all links to SO posts in *Inbox*, *Achievements*, and SO link in *Communities* panel.

And since 4 hand-drawn red circles are worth a thousand words :

[image: 2 hand-drawn red circles and an arrow] [image: 2 other hand-drawn red circles but no arrow]

Ps: this doesn't affect `https://meta.stackoverflow.com`, not even in *Inbox* panel.

Comment: \*goes to main\* \*reproduces\* \*comes back to meta\* yep.

Comment: @Kaiido It's not outdated yet. It's still not officially supported, just getting very close to being so. HTTPS by default is still not enabled on Stack Overflow. There's still a few things that have to be done before that can happen.

Comment: +1 for near-perfect free-hand circles.

Comment: @animuson While that's true, It could still be changed to a protocol-less URL now, which uses the protocol that loaded it (would not break `http:`)

Comment: @Machavity I'm not saying this shouldn't be fixed, just replying to their observation of the tag wiki from their comment.

Comment: @animuson, my bad , I really thought it was done on SO, so I'm not even sure this problem can be called a *bug*, even if it's probably a good head-up for devs.

Comment: @animuson, could you mark this question as [tag:status-completed] ?